# Maven Specifying Compile Time Plugin

Tags: java, maven

In javac I can add compile time plugin as follows:

```
javac -cp  plugin/test/target/test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -Xplugin:TestPlugin  A.java
```

How can I achieve the same effect in maven?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Pass Compiler Arguments` is what you are searching for. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html

Comment: do I need to add  a dependency some how to  give maven  the jar file containing the plugin?

Comment: Maven finds plugins normally automatically in the maven repository. You just need to configure them.

Comment: this is a custom plugin, hence  why I was specking the class path